# Error al editar una entidad con un campo unico Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, axios

Tengo una entidad actividades con el siguiente Form Request como indica la documentación

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => "required|max:200|unique:activities,name,". $this->activity_id
    ];
}
```

Al editar envio los datos por axios:

```
    $("#frmEditActivity").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                axios.patch("/admin/actividades/" + $("#frmEditActivity #activity_id").val(), $(this).serialize())
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.loadTable();
                        toastr.success(response.data);
                        $("#mdlEdit").modal('hide');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        error.response.status == 422 ? toastr.error(error.response.data.errors.name) : "Ocurrió un error. Intentelo de nuevo!";
                    });
            });
```

y al enviar los datos recibo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'xxx' for key 'activities_name_unique

La ruta es:

```
 Route::resource('actividades', 'ActivityController', [
    'except' => 'create', 'edit', 'show',
    'names' => 'activities'
]);
```

El controlador es:

```
   public function update(ActivityRequest $request, ActivityModel $activity)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {

            if ($this->activityRepo->edit($request->all(), $activity)) {
                return response()->json('Actividad editada correctamente.');
            }

            return response()->json('Ocurrió un error. Por favor inténtelo nuevamente!');
        }

        return redirect(route('admin.activities.index'));
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código del método al que apunta la ruta ?

Comment: Ahi edité la pregunta @Dev.Joel

Comment: Tienes un modelo y no un valor directamente, en el FormRequest, debes acceder al atributo `activty_id` , prueba de la siguiente forma, `'name' => "required|max:200|unique:activities,name,". $this->activity->activity_id`

Answer (score 0):

El error es que intenta acceder  a un campo (`$this->activity_id`) dentro  del `FormRequest` que no existe.

Al utilizar [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding) tiene acceso al objeto del modelo `ActivityModel`  a partir de este objeto, se accedería al atributo para validar que no tome en cuenta el valor de `activity_id`  para la restricción `UNIQUE`

```
return [
    'name' => "required|max:200|unique:activities,name,". $this->activity->activity_id
];
```

Si la llave primaria tendría el nombre `id`, sería

```
return [
    'name' => "required|max:200|unique:activities,name,". $this->activity->id
];
```